# HTTP Error 401.2 When trying to call an URL with username and password using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, android, http

This is my code:

```
private DefaultHttpClient httpClient;

public HttpAPIRequest(String authScope, int port, Credentials credentials){
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(authScope, port), 
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword()));
}

public String request(String apiUrl) throws ClientProtocolException, IllegalStateException, IOException{
    
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(apiUrl);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    return getResponseBody(response);
}
```

This is the error I get in my responsebody

> HTTP Error 401.2 -
> Unauthorized: Access is denied due to server
> configuration.Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
> credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a
> WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured to
> accept.

How would I be able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to authenticate to a URL, and the error you're receiving is indicating that you're sending a WWW-Authenticate header, but the web server is not configured to accept it.  What URL are you trying to authenticate to?  What does it look like when you try to access it with a regular web browser?

More than likely, it's configured for "forms based authentication", which means that there is a normal web page with a web form on it, which you could probably script against by posting form parameters, etc.

Comment: This is the URL i'm using: http://infonet.hszuyd.nl/infonet.jsp. Normally you would get a form, just like you said.

Comment: If you sign-in with a web browser using the same credentials that you're using within your Java program, does it work?

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer to test?  If so, can you also try Firefox, and/or a "guest" computer that wouldn't have any integrated login capabilities with the server?  I'm suspecting that it's requiring NTLM for authentication, which you'd need some additional libraries for in the least to get it to work from Java.

Comment: I tested it with IE & Chrome. Both worked. Just added some extra logging and found this line: 12-03 16:41:37.675: W/etAuthenticationHandler(3219): Authentication scheme ntlm not supported. So I'm guessing you are right about the requirement of NTLM. Do you know any good libs I could use?

Comment: That's why I asked to test with Firefox, which I believe still has NTLM disabled by default.  Since you're using HttpClient, referring to http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#NTLM is probably your best bet.